# Randomization of environment variable addresses

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, memory-address

I am using bash. I have switched off ASLR in Ubuntu 11.04 using

```
#sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```

And I have exported a variable from the shell using

```
$ export MYSHELL=/bin/sh
```

I wrote a C program to get the address of the `MYSHELL`:

```
void main(){
char* shell = getenv("MYSHELL");
if (shell)
    printf("0x%x\n", (unsigned int)shell);
}
```

It spat out `0xbffffe82`.
When I used it as a part of my attack for ret-to-libc, the address changes (although by a very small offset).
**Why does this happen?**

Also when I change the filename of the binary and use the previously successful address, it won't work, and it has been relocated to a different address. Why? In other words, **What is the relation of binary names and environment variable addresses?** Is this a protection feature by bash? How do I switch this off?

Note: this is not homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack layout at program startup is documented [here](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html). It should be obvious why changing the name of the program (length really) changes the layout.