# Address of environment variable different for each directory

Tags: bash, shell, memory, makefile, libc

I'm writing a return-to-libc attack. My script retrieves the system(), exit() and shell addresses as follows (it's a sh script that calls some c programs):

Create the environment variable for the xh shell:
    `export egg=/bin/xh`

Retrieve the address of the xh shell: `printf("%p\n", getenv("egg"));`

Get the address of system(): `void (*system_addr)(int) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "system");`

Get the address of exit(): `void (*exit_addr)(int) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "exit");`

I then overflow the buffer with the correct amount of filler + address of `system()` + address of `exit()` + address of `/bin/xh`.

When I run my exploit (`./exploit.sh`) the xh shell is dropped correctly. The problem is when I create a simple Makefile to run my script, I get a segmentation fault. The Makefile looks like this:

```
all:
./exploit8.sh
```

My guess is that the addresses of environment variables depend on the name with which the program is called, as is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781494/randomization-of-environment-variable-addresses). This is true because I tested changing the name of the vulnerable program and the address I had to provide depended on the (length) of the name.

I need a way to find the correct address of `egg` that is independent of the name of the vulnerable program. Is there an elegant way to do this instead of brute-forcing until the xh shell is dropped?

I've also read that the addresses of `system()` and `exit()` change with `make` but I don't think that's my problem since I dynamically load the addresses in my exploit.

**EDIT**

I've just tried to print the address of `egg` and then brute-forced by checking all 256*256 addresses nearby but no address hit the spot. It seems that the address of `egg` is completely different when using `make`.

Comment: If you can `printf` the address of the `egg` envvar, why can't you store it and compute the differences yourself?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned brute-forcing the correct offset as a possible solution but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. Another problem is that I've just tried to brute-force it and none of the 256*256 nearby addresses hit the spot. I think the address is completely different when using `make`.

Comment: To _compute the differences_ does not mean _brute-forcing_.